# Why does Idle keep crashing? (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, python-2.6, python-idle

I just installed python 2.6 on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard) and when I start IDLE it keeps quitting!

I removed all the installations of python by: 
rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework

and then re-installed it and I still get the same problem :(

Any ideas what it might be?

Thanks

Comment: I also re-started the computer just to make sure, but that didn't make a difference!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are undoubtedly using a version of Python that is dynamically linking to the Apple-supplied Tcl/Tk 8.5 in OS X 10.6.  That version of Tcl/Tk is seriously flawed.  There are several easy ways to avoid the problem, the simplest being to install a current Python 2.7 (or now out-of-date 2.6) [installer from python.org](http://www.python.org/download/) and, for the 64-bit/32-bit installers, install an up-to-date [ActiveTcl 8.5](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads).  There is more information [here](http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/).

I should add that, while that is by far the most common problem with IDLE on OS X 10.6, it is possible there could be another cause.  Take a look at the system.log (with `Console.app`) you are launching IDLE.app or start IDLE from a shell and see what error messages are being reported.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I installed 3.2 and it's working fine. I want to use 2.6 because I want to use pygame and isn't compatible with 3.2

Comment: What messages are in the system log?  Here's one other thing to try: quit all copies of IDLE, then from a Terminal shell, type `mv ~/.idlerc ~/.idlerc-OLD` then try IDLE again.